# SDK Platform Tools release

Tags: android, sdk, platform-tools

Although all my libraries are up-to-date, the version of SDK platform tools is a problem because it remains lower than the current version (Android SDK Platform-Tools is 26.0.2, Build is 27.0.1). So from my build.gradle, I have :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
```

that shows an error

> Found versions 27.0.1, 26.0.1, 25.2.0 . Example include com.android.support..."

even with many invalidate cache and restarts.

So my question is: *should I downgrade my targetSDKversion to 26 or maybe 25, or can I run my project with this error message?* I use AS 3.1 Canary 4.

Comment: After downgrading all my stuff to 26.1, same problem occured again when came some google map implementations and/or multidex lib. Error showed there were conflictual versions (26.0.1,25.2...) with mediarouter - upon the support-v4:26.1.0' or the appcompat-v7:26.1.0'.(deleting one support makes the error jump to the next one)

I set :

implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'

and the error is gone. I will try to go back to Build 27.0.1.